# How can I update the value of a single object's property held by a parent component in React TS?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a parent component which has a pre-populated object held in state, from which I need to update a single property from its children's children (So grandchildren, I guess). like so:

```
const NewTicketView: React.FC = () => {

    const [newTicket, setNewTicket] = useState<TicketRequestDTO>({
        title: '',
        description: '',
        priority: '',
        userId: -1,
        classificationId: -1,
        areaId: -1
    });

    return (
        <Grid>
            <TitleArea />
            <OptionsArea newTicketState={[newTicket, setNewTicket]} />
            <DescriptionArea />
            <ButtonsArea />
        </Grid>
    );
    
}

const OptionsArea: React.FC<UpdateNewTicket> = ({ newTicketState }) => {

    return (
        <Container>
            <Wrapper>
                <InputComponentSmall
                    title={REACT_APP_TITLE}
                    placeholder={REACT_APP_TITLE}
                />
                <SelectBox
                    options={prioritiesArray}
                    newTicketState={newTicketState}
                    propertyToUpdate={'String representing a property in newTicket'}
                />
                <SelectBox
                    options={data?.classification}
                    newTicketState={newTicketState}
                    propertyToUpdate={'String representing a property in newTicket'}
                />
                <SelectBox
                    options={data?.area}
                    newTicketState={newTicketState}
                    propertyToUpdate={'String representing a property in newTicket'}
                />
            </Wrapper>
        </Container>
    );
    
}

const SelectBox: React.FC<SelectBoxWithUpdate> = ({ title, renderColorBar, options, newTicketState, propertyToUpdate}) => {

    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("Low");

    const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
        const index = e.target.selectedIndex;
        const value = e.target[index].innerText;
        setSelectedOption(value);


        // I've trying to update it here through "propertyToUpdate", which represents a property in newTicket.
        
        if(newTicketState !== undefined) {

            const [newTicket, setNewTicket] = newTicketState;


            if(propertyToUpdate !== undefined) {

               // Something like this.

               newTicket[propertyToUpdate] = 'some value coming from select box';

               setNewTicket(newTicket);

            }

        }


    }

    return (
        <Select>
            <Wrapper>
                <span>{title}</span>
                {renderColorBar && <ColorBar priorityStatus={selectedOption} />}
            </Wrapper>
            <select id={title} onChange={handleChange}>
                {
                    options && options.map((option, idx) => {
                        return (
                            <option key={idx} value={option.id ?? idx}>{option.description}</option>
                        );
                    })
                }
            </select>
        </Select>
    );

}
```

The idea is to update that object's state when the select boxes change value, but so far TypeScript has been dunking on me hard.

Main error I've getting is **'string' can't be used to index type '{}'**, I've searched around stackoverflow but none of the answers I found could be applied so far.

Could someone lend me a hand or point me in the right direction?

I've tried setting up a function that would be passed down to the children, so the parent's object could be dinamically updated through a string that represents a property. It takes in just a Partial, but still, TypeScript isn't having it.

```
// Passed to children
const updateNewTicket = ( updatedProperty: Partial<TicketRequestDTO>): void => {
 
   setNewTicket({ ...newTicket, ...updatedProperty });

}

// On children, didn't work
updateNewTicket({ propertyToUpdate: 'some value' });
```

No matter what kind of check I make inside handleChange() on the SelectBox component, I just can't get TypeScript to accept "propertyToUpdate" as a valid property from newTicket.

Following check also wasn't successful:

```
if(propertyToUpdate !== undefined && newTicket.hasOwnProperty(propertyToUpdate)) {

    // Still won't let me access it.
    newTicket[propertyToUpdate] = 'some value';          

}
```

Edit: These are the errors I get:

**'string' can't be used to index type '{}'**.

I get **Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'** when I try this:

```
newTicket[propertyToUpdate as keyof typeof newTicket] = 'some value';
```

And I get **Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'TicketRequestDTO'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'TicketRequestDTO'** when I simply try this instead:

```
newTicket[propertyToUpdate] = 'some value';
```

Comment: What errors do you get

Comment: I updated with the errors I get.